# Recent Email Sending Summary with Job Name

Tags: marketing-cloud

I need to generate the same report that Recent Email Sending Summary gives, but instead of the email name, I want to show the name you put when you create the "User-Initiated Email Interaction".
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The standard reports in the Catalog cannot be modified, however Marketing Cloud does allow you to create Custom reports if **Discover** is enabled for your account. You can contact Salesforce to see if they will enable it for your Instance.